# Exception "client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'" while trying to access WCF over HTTPS

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, https, anonymous

Please help with this issue. I get above this exception - The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' when trying to access the service from the client.  I have tried everything mentioned on the earlier forums and I still have the problem. I was trying to implement WCF service over https.

1. Hosted WCF service on IIS and
2. I added the certificate to the store
3. On the client we get the certificate and pwd from the user and assign it in the code

Please find my web.config and client code snippents below-

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>   

<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
        <serviceActivations></serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
                        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="50000000" />
        <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
        <!--This section is optional with the new configuration model
       introduced in .NET Framework 4.-->

  <service name="Oz.HL7.NIXPDQV3.NIXManager_PortTypeClient" behaviorConfiguration="NIX_Behavior_HTTPS">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://localhost:10787/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="INIXManager_PortType" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpsBinding_INIXManager"
    bindingNamespace="urn:ihe:iti:NIXv3:2007" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexHttpsBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpsBinding_INIXManager" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
             allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                 enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_INIXManager" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
                        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
                    </transport>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
                </security>
            </binding>               

        </wsHttpBinding>
        <mexHttpBinding>
            <binding name="mexBinding" />
        </mexHttpBinding>
              <mexHttpsBinding>
                <binding name="mexHttpsBinding" />
              </mexHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <!--<endpoint address="http://localhost:10787/NIXManager.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_INIXManager" contract="INIXManager_PortType"
         name="NIXManager_Binding_HTTP" />-->
  <endpoint address="https://localhost:10787/NIXManager.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="WSHttpsBinding_INIXManager" contract="INIXManager_PortType"
         name="NIXManager_Binding_HTTPS" />           
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NIX_Behavior_HTTP">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
                <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
                <behavior name="NIX_Behavior_HTTPS">
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            <behavior name="NIX_Behavior_HTTPS-old">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate>
                        <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />
                    </clientCertificate>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="084509de9a36684453edaebbc52bfd26f504f065" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Client side code to call service-

```
    //wcf service proxy       
    NIXManager_PortTypeClient client;
    //Get certificate details from the UI (setting)
                AppSetting setting = settings.CurrentSetting;
                bool IsSecure = setting.V3SettingsObject.Secure;
                if (IsSecure)
                {
                    client = new NIXManager_PortTypeClient("NIX_Binding_HTTPS");
                    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(setting.V3SettingsObject.CertificatePath, setting.V3SettingsObject.CertificatePassword);

                    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;

        //Validate Certificate
                    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);                              

                }
                else
                {
                    client = new NIXManager_PortTypeClient("NIX_Binding_HTTP");

                }                   
                client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(setting.V3SettingsObject.URL);
```

I have been struggling with this for days. Please let me know what else I need to do. Any kind of input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really sure your service is hosted in IIS? The baseAddress shows a non default https port number ...